# Sync between two tables

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am working with sqlite DB in iOS. I have two tables named LEVEL and SUBJECT. [image: LEVEL TABLE][image: SUBJECT TABLE]

Now I need to sync the above two tables where the TOTALCREDITS in the LEVEL table will be updated automatically when the user add a new record in the SUBJECT table(which uses LEVELID as Foreign key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_totalcredits
AFTER INSERT ON Subject
BEGIN
    UPDATE Level
    SET TotalCredits = (SELECT SUM(Credits)
                        FROM Subject
                        WHERE LevelID = NEW.LevelID)
    WHERE LevelID = NEW.LevelID;
END;
```

However, it might be a better idea to compute the total credits dynamically (with the `SELECT SUM(...` query) whenever you need them.